# Can't convert bytes to string implicitly when hashing password

Tags: python, bcrypt

I'm trying to hash a password before sending it to a database.
This is my query:

```
i=0
while ( i < len(userList)):
    query = "INSERT INTO login (created, username, password, email) VALUES (NOW(), '" + userList[i][0] + "','" + hashmodel.PasswordHash.new_password_hash(userList[i][1]) + "','" + userList[i][2] + "')"
    i += 1
    settings.database_connection.execute_sql(query)
```

and the password hash class looks like this:

```
class PasswordHash():
def new_password_hash(password):
    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    return hashed
```

First I got a error message when trying to hash a password which was not encoded: "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" and then when I added .encode('utf-8') I get "Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly".

Anyone have a solution for this?

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
from lib.models import loginmodel, appmodel, imagemodel, versionmodel, packagemodel
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/xxxx/lib/models/loginmodel.py", line 7, in <module>
class Login(basemodel.BaseExtModel):
  File "/Users/xxxx/Documents/xxxx/lib/models/loginmodel.py", line 21, in Login
query = "INSERT INTO login (created, username, password, email) VALUES (NOW(), '" + userList[i][0] + "','" + hashmodel.PasswordHash.new_password_hash(userList[i][1]) + "','" + userList[i][2] + "')"
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Firstly, never ever ever use string concatenation to build up a database query. Secondly, what is `userList[i][1]`? Where does it come from? Thirdly, please show the full errors before and after adding the encode.

Comment: userList is a test list atm and i, 1 is the password string. I will include the full error message in an edit